# Dagger 2: How to use injection with a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` to inject components into an activity.

`AndroidInjection` also has an overloaded method that takes `android.app.Fragment` as a parameter. But my fragments extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and there is no corresponding method.

**Question:** How to use injection if a fragment extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Comment: have you tried `AndroidSupportInjection.inject()` from `dagger-android-support` ?

Comment: @xhamr thank you, it will probably work. But for now after I added the suggested code and declared `DispatchingAndroidInjector` for my fragment some wired things started failing demanding @Provides-annotated method... I'm trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For support library fragments you need to use support injection. Here some example:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, // Important
        ActivityModule.class,
        FragmentModule.class
})

public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {

    void inject(App app);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

Application, you can use DaggerApplication or simple HasSomeIjection if you need for example [Multidex implementation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle):

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication implements
    HasActivityInjector,
    HasFragmentInjector {

    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector;
    @Inject DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector;
    private AppComponent mComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
        mComponent.inject(this);
    }

    // Dependency Injection
    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector() {
        return fragmentInjector;
    }
}
```

Next module:

```
@Module
public abstract class FragmentModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ContactsFragment bindContactsFragment();
}
```

Activity module:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ContactsActivity bindContactsActivity();
}
```

And fragment:

```
import com.some.ContactsPresenter;
import dagger.android.support.DaggerFragment;

public class ContactsFragment extends DaggerFragment {

    @Inject
    ContactsPresenter mContactsPresenter;

    // .....
}
```

If you don't want use the DaggerFragment, you can open its implementation and copied to your fragment with necessary changes. The main feature here is using AndroidSupportInjectionModule. Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you. I had to fix several more issues but eventually it worked. I still can't get why such a simple pattern as DI has such a complex implementation in Android. I hope things will get better in future but for now I can hardly force myself completing what I planned to do in Android.

Comment: Technically the shortcut is to use service locator pattern inside objects created for you by the system. That way you don't need to create an unscoped subcomponent and a dispatching injector for hierarchic lookup to find the injector that can handle the exact type (dagger-android).